# Add multiple images in one cell in different position

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to add multiple images in one cell in openpyxl.
Below is my code.
aa is list of image url. This code giving an output in which the images are overlapping in a cell. But I want images not to overlapped.

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

r = http.request('GET',aa[j])
image_file = io.BytesIO(r.data)
if image_file:

 img = Image(image_file)
 img.height=100
 img.width =100
 if img:
   # ws.row_dimensions[new_row].height = 100
    ws.add_image(img,'F'+str(new_row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that new line operator in between lines or images solve the overlap

In my experience, I write very long text using new line(\n).
Like this
worksheet.cell('B4').value = "Line 1\nLine 2\n"